# Identifying if a website has AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm wondering if there is a easy way to identify a website uses Ajax requests.

I went through the following article,

http://www.zansule.com/2010/08/how-to-tell-if-a-site-is-using-ajax/

Excerpt from the article :

> "With the XHR console opened, run the suspected Ajax based operation and monitor the console for any requests being sent which indicates the operation to be Ajax driven. Note that the XHR console only shows Xml Http Requests"

Does this mean any requests shown in the XHR console indicates that the website has AJAX requests?

For example, I went to amazon.com, searched for Apple iPhone 5S and clicked on reviews and it did show requests in the XHR Console. Please advise if my understanding is correct.

Comment: xhr =- xml-http-request, the original MS name for what's now known as "ajax"

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?

Comment: do be away that there are other ways to perform the verb _ajax_ that don't use XMLHttpRequests

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you open the developer tools, click on the Network tab, and choose the "XHR" filter, the developer tools will only show you XHR (XML HTTP Requests) requests that were performed by the site. These are the AJAX calls being made.